# Creating a new wordpress user with webservice

Tags: web-services, wordpress, registration

I am having my webservice for my mobile app which written using JAVA.  I am creating a signup process in my mobile.  So when I call an webservice I have to create a Wordpress user.

I like to know is there any way I can call a wordpress plugin or some wordpress WS code from my mobile directly to insert a wordpress user.

Thanks in advance.

Dilip

Comment: You will have to custom code this. Will these users also have to be able to login via the webservice? Or is it only register?

Comment: Yes they will be able to login via webservice.  I can have the login code in Java WS. by comparing the password and user email address.

Comment: Did you ever have a look at how a WP password is stored in the DB? It's not like it's default md5...

Comment: Yes I agree..  I also saw a WP plugin that will make default pass configuration as MD5.. So I planned to use it.

Comment: You could do that, I advice against it tough, md5 is unsave. http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php#refsect1-function.md5-notes google it you will get more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread on WordPress forumn explains in detail what you want to do. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-user-via-php

Comment: Thank you sudar.. do you know how to create a WP using using java and mysql insert query..